# Moving from Machines to Dumbells

Tags: programs, freeweights

When switching from Machines to Free Weights (Dumbbells) what are the things you need to take into consideration?

Answer (score 4):

Something to consider:

Machines restrict your range of motion.  You are going to have less restriction on range of motion with dumbbells.  Generally this means that machines encourage good form.  With dumbbells you will have to focus on form because there is no machine to do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Dumbells are "heavier" than machines, why ?

because dumbells work on the balance and not only the weight like machines.

Comment: Generally is there a normal percentage of how much more difficult it is or does it depend on the person. For example, I can do 80kg Chest Press on a Machine (Male, 17, 79kg), so what should I start off with dumbbells at (or should I just goto like 20kg in each arm and then hope to go up next time)?

Comment: @e__ I don't really know, i'm using both ! You can maybe use a little more than 20kg. Try it ! 20kg is too light ? no problemo take heavier ! :D

Comment: It depends on the person. Dumbbells use more muscles because you have to stabilize the weight through the lifting motion. This means that the difficulty will depend on how strong your stabilizing muscles are, as well as which ones you are using. I'd suggest starting at 50% weight.